# Как правильно прописать команду исключения ботом участника беседы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Примера кода к сожалению не имею, но хотел бы попросить более опытных Питонистов примерно показать как прописывать такую команду

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/messages.removeChatUser. Можете вызвать этот метод через библиотеку `vk_api`. Надеюсь, ключ сообщества у Вас уже есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании библиотеки `vk_api` вполне можно исключить участника из беседы:

```py
session = vk_api.VkApi(...)
api = session.get_api()

...

chat_id = ... # event.chat_id
user_id = ... # event.obj.from_id
#               к примеру, если мы. лонгпуллим ивенты

...

api.messages.removeChatUser(chat_id=chat_id, user_id=user_id)
```

Бот при этом должен быть администратором в чате.

Comment: Это мне помогло, но у меня ещё 1 к вам вопросик, а как сделать так что бы при упоминание пользователя считывало его id? Пример прописи сообщения "кик @id367489308 (Вова)"

Comment: Вроде бы в сообщении будет подстрока форматом `[id367489308|Вова]`. По крайней мере с упоминаниями (то есть что-то в виде `@чацкий`) это так, только присутствует спец. символ `@`: к примеру, `[id123456789|@чацкий]`

Comment: Я другое имел в виду, когда я в беседе прописываю команду "кик @id121212121 (Vova)" то бот не отвечает

Comment: В плане? Ошибка? Попробуйте через дебаггинг вывести сообщение от пользователя, а потом, зная формат записи упоминания, распарсьте его, в итоге вы получите нужный `user_id`