# Как правильно прописать код (Кик Из Беседы) что бы при команде с упоминанием исключало из беседы

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Мне помогли написать код для исключения пользователя из беседы, но к сожалению при прописи команды в беседе [id134674876|Владислав] бот на неё не реагирует, как можно это исправить?

"Правка" Мой вопрос заключается в том, как правильно прописать "response" что бы оно реагировало на "id" пользователя ВК

Прикрепляю код команды.

```
    chat_id = event.chat_id
    user_id = event.obj.from_id


  if response == "кик":
            api.messages.removeChatUser(chat_id=chat_id, user_id=user_id)
```

При прописи команды в консолии она отображаеться

> Текст Сообщения: кик [id134674876|Владислав]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно прописать команду исключения ботом участника беседы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1068723/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8b)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решением было добавление регулярного выражения rs.search

Вот как выглядит законченный код

```py
                if response[0:3] == "кик":
                user_id = re.search("\d{1,}", response)
                print(user_id[0])
                api.messages.removeChatUser(chat_id=chat_id, user_id=int(user_id[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

если правильно понял, вам нужно извлечь значение id для удаления определённого человека.

```
message = "кик [id134674876|Владислав]"

user_id = int(''.join([i for i in message if i.isdigit()]))
print(user_id) #134674876
```

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, когда в сообщениях ввожу команду кик @id121212123 (Владислав) бот видит, но не реагирует на неё

Comment: Скорее всего у бота недостаточно прав, сделайте его администратором

Comment: Он администратор, в противном случае он бы не видел сообщений. Также проблема в том, что если на место user_id я вписываю айди пользователя, то при команде кик (без упоминания) оно исключает этого пользователя. Мой вопрос заключается в том, как правильно прописать "response" что бы оно реагировало на "id" пользователя ВК вместе с текстом "кик"

Comment: попробуйте user_id=int(user_id), в методе, который вам предоставил, user_id - строка, а в api контантакта user_id должен быть int

Comment: 0 на массу, мне кажется проблема не в user_id а в самой команде, ибо в коде команда кик без упоминания, а я пишу её с упоминанием, по этому её не видит бот. Вот только я не знаю как вписать это упоминание в саму команду

Comment: Может вам писать [кик 134674876]

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103218/discussion-between---and-jackwolf).